# How to fit data to only half of a model

Tags: fitting

[image]

```
pIDmm = {{1, 4.}, {2, 4.}, {3, 0.}, {4, 5.}, {5, 4.}, {6, 8.}, {7, 
  12.}, {8, 11.}, {9, 27.}, {10, 28.}, {11, 41.}, {12, 49.}, {13, 
  36.}, {14, 133.}, {15, 97.}, {16, 168.}, {17, 196.}, {18, 
  189.}, {19, 250.}, {20, 175.}, {21, 368.}, {22, 349.}, {23, 
  345.}, {24, 475.}, {25, 427.}};

sic = 11.6186 + 1.72833 x - 0.105655 x^2 + 0.0588155 x^3 - 
   0.00346728 x^4 + 0.0000699641 x^5 - 4.71206*10^-7 x^6;
```

`sic` is the model for the data pCD (blue dots). I would like to adapt or shape the model to fit the data in red dots (`pIDmm`) by phase-shifting the model and increasing its amplitude and range. But the red dots represent only the first half of the model. Is it possible to use `FindFit` using the  red dots data on only the first half of the model so as to predict the likely subsequence of data points?

Comment: What coefficients in `sic` do you think represent phase, amplitude, and range?

Comment: @JimB - good question -- answer probably none of them individually,  if a trig function like a Sin[ b x + c ] + d, then -- a-amplitude, c/b - phase shift, d - vertical shift if my memory serves me correctly. I was hoping for a genius, guess I need a new model , but could I use just half a model to syn with the new data to predict the rest of the data??

Comment: It sounds like you need a theoretically-based model that has all the features you want/need.  Otherwise you're just describing the existing data and extrapolation is at best very risky.  Whatever kind of curve you fit, you should use `NonlinearModelFit` rather than `FindFit` as `NonlinearModelFit` will give you estimates of precision.

Answer (score 1):

It's what Jim said- what parameters you can change. If, say, all the coefficients are related to phase you might have to put all of them as parameters in `Findfit` and your model will be like:

```
    model= a + b x + c x^2 + c x^3 + e x^4 + f x^5 + g x^6;
```

For the first set of data you provided (**pIDmm**) it will fit as:

```
    fit = FindFit[pIDmm,  a + b x + c x^2 + c x^3 + e x^4 + f x^5 + g 
          x^6, {a, b, c, d , e, f, g}, x];
    Show[ListPlot[pIDmm],  Plot[model /. fit, {x, 0, 25}, PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image]

However, If you want to fit combined data points of **pIDmm** and **sic**, first combine them in a list and obtain a fit which will depend on relative strength and number of points. For ex:

```
      data = Table[{x, sic + RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 3]]}, {x, 0, 56.5, 56.5/25}];
      fit2 = FindFit[Sort[Join[pIDmm, data]], 
             a + b x + c x^2 + c x^3 + e x^4 + f x^5 + g x^6, {a, b, c, 
             d , e, f, g}, x];
      Show[ListPlot[Sort[Join[pIDmm, data]]], Plot[model /. fit2, {x, 0, 55}, PlotStyle -> Red], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: thanks Maeinss, okay I will try again some of your ideas

Answer (score 1):

China model adapted to Italy, black dots are new data, the model was developed from the first 60 days and then not changed.

[image]

China model adapted to US

[image]

China model adapted to Iran

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the best fit to pCD data is a gaussian bell as can be depicted. Hopelessly we don't have  pCD data...

```
pIDmm = {{1, 4.}, {2, 4.}, {3, 0.}, {4, 5.}, {5, 4.}, {6, 8.}, {7, 12.}, {8, 11.}, {9, 27.}, {10, 28.}, {11, 41.}, {12, 49.}, {13, 36.}, {14, 133.}, {15, 97.}, {16, 168.}, {17, 196.}, {18, 189.}, {19, 250.}, {20, 175.}, {21, 368.}, {22, 349.}, {23, 345.}, {24, 475.}, {25, 427.}}

f[x_] := 11.6186 + 1.72833 x - 0.105655 x^2 + 0.0588155 x^3 - 0.00346728 x^4 + 0.0000699641 x^5 - 4.71206*10^-7 x^6
fa[x_, a_, b_, c_] := a Exp[-(x - b)^2/c]
data = Sum[(f[x] - fa[x, a, b, c])^2, {x, 0, 60}];
sol = NMinimize[data, {a, b, c}, Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"]
fa0 = fa[x, a, b, c] /. sol[[2]]
gr2 = Plot[{fa0, f[x]}, {x, 0, 60}, PlotStyle -> {{Thick, Blue}, {Dashed, Red}}]
```

[image]

so we follow adjusting to pIDmm a gauss bell also

```
data2 = Sum[(fa[pIDmm[[k, 1]], a, b, c] - pIDmm[[k, 2]])^2, {k, 1, Length[pIDmm]}];
sol2 = NMinimize[data2, {a, b, c}, Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"]
fa02 = fa[x, a, b, c] /. sol2[[2]]
gr0 = ListPlot[pIDmm];
gr1 = Plot[{fa02, fa0}, {x, 0, 60}, PlotStyle -> {{Thick, Black}, {Thick, Blue}}];
Show[gr1, gr0]
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

a new model based on trig -( a Sin[b x + c] + d ) on the completed trend, results

```
   In[1246]:= trigfitCD =  a Sin[b x + c] + d /. {a -> -56.11407429814903`, 
   b -> 0.12234789054358615`, c -> 8.054346767593303`, 
   d -> 61.16172326460761`}

   Out[1246]= 61.1617 - 56.1141 Sin[8.05435 + 0.122348 x]
```

I multiplied trigfitCD * Max[ItalyDeaths]/Max[ChinaDeaths] and plotted the results
[image]

It is close but the predictive line is just the trendline amplified. I would like to fit the old model to the new data. The new data is only half of the story, so I need to fit half the old model to the new data - to get a predictive trend, is that possible with Fit or FindFit or NonlinearModelFit or something else???

Comment: You need to consult with a statistician or an epidemiologist.  What you're proposing sounds misleading at best.

Comment: @JimB as far as I understand he is talking about forecasting based on the previous trend. That's the hot topic these days in media.

Comment: I don't mean to be rude but it's a hot topic for folks who know what they're doing.  There's enough misinformation already coming from all directions.

Comment: @JimB I understand

Comment: @JimB  nothing so glamorous here, just taking a class dealing with bracketing, interpolation,  curve fitting, least square regression. I have a project to find some data, analysis it, find a trend, and test if the trend has any predictive value. I was trying to figure out what Mathematica had to offer in curve fitting. I got stuck with trying to cut the model in half and combine it with new known data to create a new predictive model, I'm guessing that is not possible???

Comment: Curve fitting is not just about learning what a piece of software has to offer.  It's also about know what kind of data you have and how it was obtained.  (Yes, I understand that this is for a classroom example but the particular data you're using -COVID-19 - has too many misleading so-called analyses already which is why I'm taking a hard-nosed approach with your question.)  In addition, your data is about counts (integers).  `FindFit` is not appropriate for that.  Also, with any polynomial fit, extrapolating too far will get you predictions of + or - $\infty$.

Comment: @JimB, thanks for your feedback - you are right there are problems with any kind prediction method and it is not something I will be writing about in the media, just a classroom exercise.  I did make a few tweaks on the polynomial when adapting it to the other countries and I am surprised how closely the China model fits that data from Iran, Italy and the US  only countries I was looking at. I will post the graphs for your feedback.